# How to store JWT token in VueX without local storage

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, vuex

How to store JWT token in VueX without local storage. Does it have an easy way? How do I store tokens?

**How to store token and Users or visitors cannot see it**

Answer (score 1):

you can just commit it using mutation, but once you refresh the page it will gone.
thats why Local Storage is needed.

Comment: How to store token and Users or visitors cannot see it

Comment: The token itself should be encrypted when you are storing it in localStorage

Comment: user can access his localstorage at anytime, because it stores in the Browser itself

Comment: token is in all of your network requests anyway, so its not that big deal.. user can get it even its not in the local storage